# Enterprise App Single App Mode doesn't always automatically boot

Tags: ios, mdm

I am currently encountering issues with an Enterprise App that is run in Single App Mode. The devices used are iPad Mini running iOS 9.3.2 & 9.3.5.
The tablets are Supervised & the MDM I am using currently is Meraki by Cisco.

When the tablet is plugged back in the app shuts down and should reboot automatically but this is not always the case. About 1/4 times the app just doesn't boot at all and the tablet is stuck on the homescreen of the operating system. You are not able to do anything anymore with the tablet except for a force-reboot which reboots the entire tablet & then almost always fires the app from the start, altho not always the case.

My question obviously is how can I fix this, is this a known issue with Single App Mode on iOS 9.3?

Answer (score 0):

Also experiencing this issue with Single App Mode on iOS devices; I've found that you can get the App to re-launch by only powering the device off and back on with just the power toggle instead of force-rebooting the device. This saves some time but still quite annoying problem.